# yii2 vendor and some files are missing from github

Tags: github, yii2

I have set up a new repo on github and pushed yii2 advanced template. Now i realized that some folders/files are missing from github like vendor and backend/web/index.php.

Anyone have idea why this is happening, i also checked my local git setup there files are present.

Comment: Check the `.gitignore` files.

Comment: Checking the Git ignores might show you why the files aren't included, but it probably won't explain *why they're being ignored*. This is likely deliberate (at least in the case of `vendor/`, which [generally *shouldn't be* tracked](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)). See [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33003277/354577) for a better answer.

Comment: @chris, thanks its working

Comment: you should not push vendor directory to git. Just your code and composer.json and composer.lock . On your production server, pull your code, and do composer install to get the same vendor directory as you have on development server

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [installation guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md).

Running `composer install` is what creates the `vendor` folder, while running `init` creates those `index.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that its happening because of .gitignore file. i removed it and its working fine for me.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on your question, these files are ignored *for a very good reason*. Rather than just removing the `.gitignore` file, it is much better to understand why they are being ignored, and how the tool is meant to be used (see [Beowulfenator's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33003277/354577)).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple idea behind missing these files, they are called `...-local.php`, because their content can vary for different developers or production conditions. All you have to do before upload yii2 to the github, check the `/environments` directory, it includes templates for the local files, so after yii2 project is copied from the github, they will be generated by `./yii init`.

Step-by-step, what should be done:

1. Configure files in `/environments/dev` and `/environments/prod` (for production). Most likely, if you don't change the yii2 project file structure or touch any of the `/config` files, you don't need to adapt them.
2. Update `/environments/index.php`, if you have updated /environments files
3. Upload the project to GitHub
4. Clone the project and run `composer install` to install dependencies
5. And finally run `./yii init` from the root folder. You will see that `...-local.php` files are now generated in certain directories the same way as they are configured in the environments.

More detailed information about this topic: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-environments